# How do I properly write with ?. in a JSX File

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have some code that creates a react component:

```
const MyMessage = ({ message }) => { 
if(message?.attachments?.length > 0){
    // We have an image
    return(
        <img
            src={message.attachments[0].file}
            alt="message-attachment"
            className='message-image'
            style={{ float: 'right' }}
        />
    )
}}
```

I get the following error pointing to the `?.` syntax

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 
        
       Error in ./src/components/MyMessage.jsx
Syntax error: C:/Users/GitHub/react_chat_app/src/components/MyMessage.jsx: Unexpected token (4:15)
```

When I remove the `?.` and replace with

`if(message.attachments.length > 0)`

it works fine.  What is wrong with my syntax when using `?.`?

Comment: @MegaMindTheCoder Which node version you are using?.Try upgrading to v14 and check.This should solve your issue

Comment: @Shubham Sharma I don't have an issue. I was trying to help Mwspencer. But thank you very much for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length wouldn't be `0` it would be `undefined` or `null`. Try:

```
const MyMessage = ({ message }) => { 
if(message?.attachments !== undefined){
    return(
        <img
            src={message?.attachments[0].file}
            alt="message-attachment"
            className='message-image'
            style={{ float: 'right' }}
        />
    )
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

While DarthVader's answer is far better, I would like to provide another solution here. You can use [`??` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) in addition to check if a value is null or undefined and assign a default value to avoid error if it is.

Example:

```
const message = undefined;
//const message = {"attachments": [1,2,3]};

const baz = message?.attachments?.length ?? 0;
//console.log(baz);

if(baz > 0){
    // We have an image
    console.log(baz);
}
```